# How Can I Validate User Name using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I want to validate the `user_name` field using REGEX with a Javascript function
I want the following requirement for a `user_name` to be filled in

- `user_name` must start with a letter
- `user_name` can contains only letters, numbers, underscore and period (.)
- `user_name` can not contain white spaces
- `user_name` can not be longer than 25 characters

How Can I make a REGEX Expression under the above mention requirements.

Comment: Make sure you are also validating the user name on the server side -- client side validation (via javascript) can **never** be relied on. If the client has javascript disabled, you'd better be checking things on the server!

Comment: You should have a bash yourself,first.  [Here's a great site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).

Comment: In addition to the resource Westie mentioned, here's another useful tool: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: What is the problem? Designing the regular expression? Implementing that regular expression in JavaScript? There are plenty of tutorials on JS and regular expressions that you can find via search engines, presumably you have tried them before asking people to investigate your problem personally. What code have you produced so far?

Answer (score 4):

you can try:

```
   /^[a-z][a-z0-9_\.]{0,24}$/i
```

Comment: Why bother with the `{1}`?

Comment: I have tried it, only one problem with it that It allows '^' character in the user name

Comment: @speakr, the OP is correct. It not only allows `^` but several others not included in the allowed list as well. Run `/^[A-z][A-z0-9_\.]{0,24}$/i.test("[]^\\")` in the browser dev tools of your choice to verify. The problem is the `[A-z]` range in both character classes. What that essentially says is `Start with an uppercase A and allow up to a lowercase z`. Note that the uppercase and lowercase letter ranges are not contiguous in the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/). This can easily be solved be just switching to `[a-z]`, particularly since the `i` case insensitive flag is included.

Answer (score 3):

Try this regexp:

```
/^[a-z][\w\.]{0,24}$/i
```

- `\w` matches `[a-z0-9_]`
- The `/i` flag makes the match case-insensitive

Please don't miss reading [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15525114/how-can-i-validate-user-name-using-regex/15525168#comment21990554_15525114).

Comment: I don't see why this working solution deserves a downvote.. :/

Answer (score 0):

Use `[A-z]` for the first character. It covers upper and lower case letters.

And you can use `[A-z0-9_.]{24}` for the other 24 characters.

`/[A-z][A-z0-9_\.]{24}/` should do it.